# Reading xlsx file using jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have tried to read an xlsx file which is stored in my system using jupyter notebook.I had run the jupyter notebook from the present directory where my file is present.But it is showing an error as "module not found error".

[image: This is the image of the code i have written and also the error i got]

[image: This is the complete traceback]

Comment: Show us the full traceback.. Also, it seems you don't have the package installed.

Comment: csv files are being read properly.all other formats are working fine except xlsx. what package do i have to install for reading xlsx files??

Comment: `xlrd` is an [optional](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/install.html#dependencies) requirement for pandas. Try `pip install xlrd`

Comment: What package are you currently using? Use xlrd for xlsx or pandas if you prefer.

Comment: i am using pandas.its working for other files but not this.

Comment: Its working after i installed xlrd. thanq @Ketan Mukadam and others

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The below code should able to access /read your excel file

```
import pandas as pd
path = ('...\\filename.xlsx')
xl = pd.ExcelFile(path)
print(xl.sheet_names)
```

The above command shows the sheets in a xlsx file

```
df1 = xl.parse('Sheet1')
```

Above command parses the sheet required

Answer (score 2):

Same outout, but this one worked for me.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel (r'C:\Users\(NAME)\Desktop\(FILENAME).xlsx')
print (df)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('file_name.xlsx', 'Sheet1')
df
```

*you must import your .xlsx file into the Jupyter notebook file...
*you may also import it into a Github repository and get the raw file then just copy and paste it into where it says 'file_name.xlsx'

[raw file URL example[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aY6t5.png)

Answer (score -1):

```
import pandas as pd
wb = pd.ExcelFile('D:\\<Excel File Name>.xlsx')
ds = wb.parse('<Sheet  Name>')
print(ds)
```